# Using B-Tree to implement findrange efficiently

Tags: b-tree

My task is to implement efficiently the findRange(x,y) method, that outputs all values greater than x and less than or equal to y.

How can I do this in a efficient way  ?

How does a findRange(x,y) method look like in B-Trees?

I don't want any code, I just want to get the idea behind this whole thing to understand it properly.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Could be even your homework? Which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: It's a learning exercise for incoming exams. Programming language is Java.